Quenching wet steam
I have an application where I want to quench wet steam with cooling water to obtain 70F liquid water. Reason is so that at the drain the water is lukewarm and will not steam up the room. Can someone check to see if my math below is actually correct for what we want to do? What I'm trying to calculate is the mass flow of 60F cooling water that I need. It started off with me way overthinking it and separating out the latent and sensible cooling but I think I can just use enthalpies in an energy balance like I did below?


m3dot=m2dot+m1dot
m3dot h3=m2dot h2+m1dot h1
m2dot (h3-h2)=m1dot (h1-h3)
hence your calculation is correct. Is this for a Newcomen steam engine or your shower? (grins)
